# paint an exterior rendered step

Tags: paint, render

Exterior step fronts have been hacked off and rendered with sand and cement.  The walls either side have had the cracked loose bits removed and repaired with the above render.

First I would like to know what is the cheapest paint that can go on the new render and the existing painted parts.

Next the weather in the UK at this time of year is not very good, so the paint needs to be able to be applied when it's not raining, but dry quickly.  Would love to do just one coat, but definitely a maximum of two.  It doesn't have to be guaranteed to last 15 years as it is just a tidy up for the 94 year old lady who should hopefully be returning home from hospital soon. I am a lady myself who is in ill health, but am going to try and do it for her voluntarily.

Next I would like to know if I can use a small roller from side to side across the front of the step risers. If so, what size roller and pile would I need to get?  The 2 walls either side are only approximately 1 metre wide by half a metre high, so hoping to only have to get 1 brush and 1 roller.

Any advice would be very much appreciated thank you.

Comment: I applaud you, but you have chose a difficult task, painting on wet surface. If you can dry it with hair blower then you are good to go.

Comment: roller goes faster, but applies thinner layer, with its pro and cons. Pro it dries faster, con it might need second coat.